# How can I convert a pandas series that contains an array of json dictionaries into a dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have a series composed of the following:

[

[{u'edu_location': u'correctly_parsed', u'edu_dates': u'correctly_parsed', u'edu_title': u'missing', u'edu_item': 1, u'edu_school': u'correctly_parsed'}, {u'edu_location': u'not_on_source', u'edu_dates': u'not_on_source', u'edu_title': u'missing', u'edu_item': 2, u'edu_school': u'correctly_parsed'}], :SHOULD BE ITS OWN ROW:

[{u'edu_location': u'correctly_parsed', u'edu_dates': u'correctly_parsed', u'edu_title': u'missing', u'edu_item': 1, u'edu_school': u'correctly_parsed'}] :SHOULD BE ITS OWN ROW:

]

Whats the best way of turning this pandas series into its own df and dynamically renaming the columns with the correspond u'edu_item' value so that they are displayed on one row rather than multiple rows?

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe looks like this:

```
>>> df
                                              column
0  [{'work_location': 'correctly_parsed', 'work_c...
```

Then you can do:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df['column'][0])
       work_company        work_dates  work_description  work_experience_item  \
0  correctly_parsed  correctly_parsed  correctly_parsed                   1.0   
1  correctly_parsed  correctly_parsed  correctly_parsed                   2.0   
2  correctly_parsed               NaN  correctly_parsed                   NaN   

      work_location        work_title  
0  correctly_parsed  correctly_parsed  
1  correctly_parsed  correctly_parsed  
2     not_on_source               NaN
```

Comment: the issue is that i want all the rows to be actually 1 row for

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Could you post your expected output as an edit to your question?